# What does "<>" mean in this PHP code?

Tags: php

```
if ($varr <> '') {

}
```

I know boolean operators "||", "&&" "AND" "OR", but "<>", I am seeing for the first time.

Comment: in SQL it means not equals, I'd guess it means the same in PHP but I'm not positive so this is just a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: It means "the developer probably came from BASIC and thought using a less well-known alias for a well-known operator is fine". :p

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Not equal to," like SQL. Exactly the same operator as `!=`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 9):

It means `!=`. And my answer has to be 30 characters long.

Comment: Ok, even though you answered it at the exact same time as 3 other people, the second sentence gets you a +1 :)

Comment: @Stargazer: well, not _exactly_ the same time, unless your clock only has 5-second resolution ;-)

Comment: @Matt Ball, just give it another minute, and the 15 second time span between the answers will be all but forgotten by SO ;)

Comment: @Star: Unless you look at the tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it's not equal to, I've always used != in php though :)

Answer (score 1):

Not equal to.

It is a comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

It is "not equal to", exactly the same as `!=` (i.e. type juggling is attempted if appropriate).

See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).